# Xcode - Disable prompt to stop running task on quit?

Tags: xcode

Is there any way to disable Xcode's "Stop running task" prompt that appears when you try to quit Xcode or close a workspace? I would like it to act as though I always hit "Stop Tasks".

I see nothing in the settings, but perhaps there is something I could do using `defaults` from the command line?

[image: Prompt]